# C# client object

Tags: c#, object, sharepoint, client

I want to read a specific SharePoint list into a datatable. I am struggeling to read the Lookup Values.
Example:
Customer list, each customer is assigned to a team member. The Team members are a lookup of the Team member list.

I have the following questions:
1.) How can I get the Information which list is linked to this lookup field?
2.) How can read the field, gets the value or the index?

I added my function below, many thanks for helping a desperate novice in SharePoint...

Regards

Volker

```
   public System.Data.DataTable ReadDatafromSPList(ClientContext clientContext, string ListName, string ViewName)
    {
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
        View view = list.Views.GetByTitle(ViewName);
        ViewFieldCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields;
        clientContext.Load(view);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = view.ViewQuery;

       ListItemCollection ListColletion = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(list);
        clientContext.Load(ListColletion);
        clientContext.Load(viewFields);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

       string[] headers  = view.ViewFields.ToArray();
       System.Data.DataTable dTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
       foreach (string header in headers)
           {
                dTable.Columns.Add(header);
           }

        string str="";

       foreach (ListItem item in ListColletion)
         {
               dTable.Rows.Add(dTable.NewRow());
              foreach (string header in headers)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      str = item[header].ToString();
                      if (str == "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue")
                      {
                        //??????????????????

                       //??????????????????
                      }
                      dTable.Rows[dTable.Rows.Count - 1][header] = str;
                  }
                  catch
                  {
                      dTable.Rows[dTable.Rows.Count - 1][header] = "";
                  }
              }
           }
      return    dTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do try this..

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ServerText.Text);
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
context.Load(list);
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Id");
table.Columns.Add("Title");
foreach (ListItem item in items)
table.Rows.Add(item.Id, item["Title"]);
```